# Issue while adding private tag to DICOM using MergeCom

Tags: c++, dicom

I am creating a DICOM file using MergeCom DICOM toolkit. I need to add some private tags to the DICOM file where we keep our data. But the tag is not coming properly as expected. i.e. we are inserting the tag `0077, 0011` to the DICOM file. But once the same is inserted and saved, if we open the DICOM file in any viewer, the tag is displayed as `0077, 1011`. Instead of `0011`, it is coming `1011`.

I am using the API `MC_Add_Private_Block` to create a private block and API `MC_Add_Private_Attribute` to insert the private tag. API `MC_Set_pValue_From_Int` is being used to set the value of the tag.

Is this issue related to MergeCom toolkit ?
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a private creator element to properly reserve a block of elements in a private group. They will always be (gggg,00xx) where xx is 10-FF. I would guess that MergeCom assumes in your case it's (0077,0010).

(0077,0011) is not a valid attribute for anything except a private creator of the (0077,11xx) attribute block.